# Sending ActiveWorkbook as an attachment in email

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have code that saves a file a couple of times, the second as an .xlsx file to send externally without the VBA code in the Developer tab.

In testing when a couple of people try the file it works, but it doesn't work later in the day or the next day etc and nothing has changed. I'm using the latest Office suite.

In the code below xxx represents private info.

```vb
Sub SubmitRequest()

Dim OlApp As Object
Dim NewMail As Object
Dim sMsgBody As String

If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Data").Range("A8")) = True Then
    'Cell A8 is not blank
    MsgBox "xxx", vbOKOnly + vbQuestion
    
Else

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    'SaveAsXSLX() to remove code and send externally, works fine
    Worksheets(Array("xx", "xxx")).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="xxx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      
    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set NewMail = OlApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    With NewMail
        .to = "xxx@xxx"
        .CC = "xxx@xxx"
        .ReplyRecipients.Add "xxx.xxx"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "xxx@xxx"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName

        sMsgBody = "Hi xxx," & vbCr & vbCr
        sMsgBody = sMsgBody & "xxx?" & vbCr
        sMsgBody = sMsgBody & "xxx," & vbCr & vbCr
    
        .body = sMsgBody
        .Send
        
        End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set NewMail = Nothing
    Set OlApp = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
    MsgBox "xxx" & Worksheets("Data").Range("H4").Value

    'Save and close request
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Application.Quit
    
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: *"does not work"* is no usful error description. You need to explain what's wrong with your code and which errors you get in which line. Or if no errors then explain the actual behavior compared with the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever working with multiple workbooks make sure you call them explicitly. For example in `Worksheets("Data").Range("A8")` it is not defined in which workbook the worksheet `Data` is. So Excel needs to make a guess and that is where it can go wrong.

If you use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A8")` then you don't give Excel room to guess.

---

Also make sure you know the difference between the following 2 statements:

- `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook the code is written in. This will never change.
- `ActiveWorkbook` is the worbook that has focus (is on top). This will change easily by any mouse click or anything else that changes focus.

So I recommend whenever you really need to use `ActiveWorkbook` make sure you set it to a variable so it cannot be changed by a user click or something.

---

Then you have a `Application.Quit` in the end of your procedure. This will close the entire Excel Application. Not sure if this is what you wanted.

---

Taking all this into account your code would look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SubmitRequest()
    If IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A8")) Then
        'Cell A8 is not blank
        MsgBox "xxx", vbOKOnly + vbQuestion
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        ThisWorkbook.Save
        'SaveAsXSLX() to remove code and send externally, works fine
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("xx", "xxx")).Copy

        Dim NewWb As Workbook 'get the new workbook set to a variable so we fix it
        Set NewWb = ActiveWorkbook
        NewWb.SaveAs Filename:="xxx"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Dim OlApp As Object
        Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        Dim NewMail As Object
        Set NewMail = OlApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next
        With NewMail
            .to = "xxx@xxx"
            .CC = "xxx@xxx"
            .ReplyRecipients.Add "xxx.xxx"
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "xxx@xxx"
            .Attachments.Add NewWb.FullName

            Dim sMsgBody As String
            sMsgBody = "Hi xxx," & vbCr & vbCr & _
                       "xxx?" & vbCr & _
                       "xxx," & vbCr & vbCr
            .body = sMsgBody

            .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set NewMail = Nothing
        Set OlApp = Nothing

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        MsgBox "xxx" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("H4").Value

        'Save and close request
        NewWb.Close SaveChanges:=True

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Application.Quit 'this will quit Excel completely. Are you sure?
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally you should consider some kind of error reporting. Because for now if an error occurs between `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` you will never notice as all error are silenced. So if an error occurs it won't notify you and just do nothing instead.
Check out [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling).

Comment: thanks for you reply - apologies I wasnt clear, the code runs all the way to the end but there is no email sent, I have removed the screen updating in some instances to check for errors ,but nothing happens in terms of creating/opening outlook to send the email. I will defs look into the active workbook - i had earlier put in code that closes all other workbooks except this one to ensure nothing is sent in error, but the way you mentioned above will defs make it more robust. 

Not working is the email not sending at all, or just not even opening outlook.

Comment: @T_M_ Then remove `On Error Resume Next` in order to see your errors. This line hides all error messages. You are not able to debug a code that has this line.

Comment: When I've removed on error, the code stops at the line ".send"  with the error message "Operation failed. The messaging interfaces have returned an unknown error. If the problem persists, restart outlook. Outlook does not recognise one of more names. I've restarted both PC & Outlook a couple of times. still the same issue. Just confuses me because it works sometimes. I've been using the same two email addresses throughout, both internal.

Comment: @T_M_ Well, first of all you see how important it is to **never** mute error reporting! • Actually this does not look like a code issue but a general Outlook issue. Checkout: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+outlook+Operation+failed.+The+messaging+interfaces+have+returned+an+unknown+error.&oq=vba+outlook+Operation+failed.+The+messaging+interfaces+have+returned+an+unknown+error. • There seems to be something wrong with your Outlook.

Comment: got there in the end, thanks for your help. It was ".ReplyRecipients.Add "xxx.xxx" causing an issue because I tried to put multiple email addresses when it required a new line per email address. Thanks again will bear the above in mind when using the code again.